# How to change style multiple times?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a graph and I want to display a border around a text. My code works, but only 1 time for adding or removing the border, but my event MouseEnter/MouseLeave works multiple times. Why is this?

```
const Custom_border = (index) =>
{
        data_utilisation.map((data_utilisation, index_1) => 
        {
            if(index == index_1)
            {
                console.log("In")
                const add_border = document.getElementById(index)
                return add_border.classList.add('nice_border')
                
            }
        })
    return null
}
```

```
return <Cell cursor="pointer" key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colored[0]} onMouseEnter={() => Custom_border(index)} onMouseLeave={() => Custom_no_border(index)}/>
```

All the BarChart (Recharts API) :

```
<BarChart
         width={400}
         height={250}
         data={data_utilisation}>

<CartesianGrid opacity={0.1} vertical={false} horizontal={false}/>
<XAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} stroke="#eeeeee00"/>
<YAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} stroke="#eeeeee00"/>
                    
<Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#8884d8">
{
  data_utilisation.map((data_utilisation, index) => 
                                        
  {
     if(data_utilisation.uv <= 5000)
     {
       return <Cell className="my_cell" cursor="pointer" key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colored[0]} onMouseEnter={() => Custom_border(index)} onMouseLeave={() => Custom_no_border(index)}/>
     }
    else if(data_utilisation.uv > 5000 && data_utilisation.uv <= 10000)
    {
      return <Cell cursor="pointer" key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colored[1]} onMouseEnter={() => Custom_border(index)} onMouseLeave={() => Custom_no_border(index)}/>
     }
     else
     {
       return <Cell cursor="pointer" key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colored[2]} onMouseEnter={() => Custom_border(index)} onMouseLeave={() => Custom_no_border(index)}/>
      }
      })
      }
</Bar>
</BarChart>
```

The code for display a text next to the Barchart who i need to put the border on :

```
<div className="Text_1">
{
   data_utilisation.map((data_utilisation, index) => 
   {
   if(data_utilisation.uv <= 5000)
   {
      return <p id={index} style={{ color: colored[0]}}>{data_utilisation.name} : {data_utilisation.uv}</p>
   }
     else if(data_utilisation.uv > 5000 && data_utilisation.uv <= 10000)
     {
       return <p id={index} style={{ color: colored[1]}}>{data_utilisation.name} : {data_utilisation.uv}</p>
     }
else
{
 return <p id={index} style={{ color: colored[2]}}>{data_utilisation.name} : {data_utilisation.uv}</p>
}})}
</div>
```

Comment: Where does `Cell` come from? It that a component that you created? It is generally not recommended to modify DOM elements that are managed by react as react will not be aware of changes made to the element and may override it during consecutive renders.

Comment: Cell is an element of recharts api, https://recharts.org/en-US/

Comment: What i can use instead of change an element without modify DOM ?

Comment: The whole point of react is that you don't modify the DOM. React will do that for you. You should use component state and props to alter what is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your use case correctly, you want to show a border when the user hovers over a cell. You can achieve this with css, you just need to figure out how to select the Cell component. Let's assume it has a class name called `my-cell`, you could simply add the following css.

```
.my-cell:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

To figure out what the class name of the component is, you can inspect it on the dom, if it doesn't have one you can add it like this:

```
return <Cell className="my-cell" ... />
```

Comment: Hi, it's more harder than that, i display a BarChart with Recharts Api. When my mouse enter on a Bar, i need to display a border around a text i put next to the BarChart. After some hour, i managed to display what i want but this only work one time.

Comment: I put all the code if you want to check that.